# php display results from mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, while-loop

Not done any php database work for years, fairly simple question I'm sure for anyone with experience, below is my code it should take all the results from the database and display these to a table with links:

```
<?php
include('session.php');
?>
<html">
<head>
<title>Welcome </title>
</head> 
<body>
  <h1>Welcome <?php echo $login_session; ?></h1> 

  <form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>File:</p>
<input type="file" name="Filename"> 
<p>Description:</p>
<textarea rows="10" cols="35" name="Description"></textarea>
<br/>
<input TYPE="submit" name="upload" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<hr/>
<p>Uploaded Files</p>

<?php
//include('config.php');
$query1=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT filepath,filename,description FROM `filedetails`");
echo "<table><tr><td>filepath</td><td>filename</td><td></td><td></td>";
while($query2=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
{
echo "<tr><td>".$query2['filepath']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$query2['filename']."</td>";
echo "<td><a href='edit.php?id=".$query2['id']."'>Edit</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=".$query2['id']."'>x</a></td><tr>";
}
?>
<h2><a href = "logout.php">Sign Out</a></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

So the line it's failing on is

```
while($query2=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
```

The error message is:

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\welcome.php on line 27

Comment: You're mixing both MySQLi (`mysqli_query)` and MySQL (`mysql_fetch_array`) syntax. MySQL functions are deprecated in PHP 5.5, and **removed** in PHP 7, so please don't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `mysql_fetch_array` you need to use `mysqli_fetch_array`.

```
<?php
    include('session.php');
?>
<html">
    <head>
        <title>Welcome </title>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome <?php echo $login_session; ?></h1> 

        <form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p>File:</p>
            <input type="file" name="Filename"> 
            <p>Description:</p>
            <textarea rows="10" cols="35" name="Description"></textarea>
            <br/>
            <input TYPE="submit" name="upload" value="Submit"/>
        </form>

        <hr/>
        <p>Uploaded Files</p>

        <?php
            //include('config.php');
            $query1=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT filepath,filename,description FROM `filedetails`");
            echo "<table><tr><td>filepath</td><td>filename</td><td></td><td></td>";
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query1))
            {
                echo "<tr><td>".$row['filepath']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['filename']."</td>";
                echo "<td><a href='edit.php?id=".$row['id']."'>Edit</a></td>";
                echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=".$row['id']."'>x</a></td><tr>";
            }
        ?>
        <h2><a href = "logout.php">Sign Out</a></h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note: I also changed your variable name to a more sensible one.

Answer (score 1):

your resource is mysqli and you try to handle with mysql_fetch_array. try to use mysqli_fetch_array. i think this will eliminate your problem

```
$resource = mysqli_query($connection, $queryString);
if(!mysqli_errno($connection)) {
  while($resultArray = mysqli_fetch_array($resource)){
    print_r($resultArray); // pseudo output for your table
  }
} else {
  echo "error\n"
  print_r(mysqli_error($connection))
}
```

And never forget to check for errors on the query

Answer (score 1):

The error lies in the mismatch of mysql and mysqli connections. As you are using mysqli_query, you should use the mysqli. Replacing the following line with error line should do the work:

```
mysqli_fetch_array($db,$query1);
```